# Criar uma query verificando duas colunas

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho uma seguinte tabela:

#### tbl_missao

- id_misssao
- nome_missao
- status
- id_guerreiro
- id_criador_da_missao

Quando o usuário cria uma missão, ele pode adicionar essa missão a ele mesmo ou pode indicar um outro usuário(guerreiro) a realizar esta missão. A lógica esta da seguinte forma:

- Ao criar uma missão sem indicar um guerreiro, cria um registro de missão para o próprio usuário que estar registrando deixando o campo `id_guerreiro = NULL`.
- Ao criar uma missão indicando o guerreiro, cria um registro na tabela contendo o identificador do guerreiro e do autor da missão.

### Problema

Gostaria de criar uma *query* que mostre o total de missões que um usuário tenha, porém é necessário criar uma condição para verificar se o `id_guerreiro` está nulo ou não.

**SE** id_guerreiro for igual a NULL, 
**ENTÃO** retorne um contador verificando a quantidade de itens que existe para o `id_criador_da_missao`

**SENÃO** retorne um contador verificando a quantidade total de itens do `id_guerreiro`.

A seguinte *query* calcula o total de itens, porém somente verificando a coluna do `id_criador_da_missao`. Existe uma maneira de verificar as duas colunas e retornar o total?

```
SELECT COUNT (id_criador_da_missao ) TOTAL FROM TBL_MISSAO
```

Comment: Você quer retornar todos no mesmo contador ou quer retornar um contador pra missões que são desse criador e missões das quais ele é o guerreiro?

Comment: @Sorack Quero retornar a quantidade total de missões que uma guerreiro possui, porém quando não tem id_guerreiro no item, tem que verificar o identificador do criador da missão que seria o próprio realizador da missão.

Comment: Certo, então a resposta que coloquei vai servir pra você

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A seguinte `query` retornará o total para você, onde a variável `@id_usuario` dever ser substituída pelo código do usuário que você está buscando:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS total
  FROM TBL_MISSAO
 WHERE (id_guerreiro IS NULL AND id_criador_da_missao = @id_usuario)
    OR (id_guerreiro = @id_usuario)
```

Comment: Realmente funcionou desta forma. Vou fazer mais alguns testes e valido sua resposta. Obrigado!